Compactness of unit sphere in 1-norm; Gamelin and Greene
In Introduction to Topology by Gamelin and Greene, I'm working an exercise to show the equivalence of norms in $\mathbb R^n$. This exercise succeeds another exercise where various equivalent formulations of equivalent norms have been given, e.g. that two norms $\|\cdot\|_a,\|\cdot\|_b$ are equivalent iff the identity map from $(\mathbb R^n,\|\cdot\|_a)$ to $(\mathbb R^n,\|\cdot\|_b)$ is bicontinuous.
Now, in showing that all norms in $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent, the authors show a given norm $\|\cdot\|$ is equivalent to the $1$-norm (and then by transitivity, we have equivalence for all norms). I have already managed to understand that the identity is continuous from $(\mathbb R^n,\|\cdot\|_1)$ to $(\mathbb R^n,\|\cdot\|)$. To show that the inverse of the identity map is continuous, the authors claim that the unit sphere in the $1$-norm is compact. I'm getting hung up on this statement, since I don't know how to go about this without using that the norms are equivalent already. How would one show the unit sphere in the $1$-norm is compact?
I know of Heine-Borel, but I'm not sure how and if it applies here. I've struggled with this statement and any help would be very appreciated. If you think there's another answer already that answers this in a concise and comprehensive way, please comment.

I think I understand now. The $1$-norm and the $2$-norm are induced by metrics which are equivalent by an earlier theorem (Theorem 4.1, but see also Exercise I.1.12 and Exercise I.4.3). By Exercise I.6.2, the identity map between these metric spaces is bicontinuous and hence preserves compact sets. In particular, the unit sphere in the $1$-norm is compact.

Good catch! Another proof using equivalence of $1-$norm and $2-$norm is that, if the unit ball of $1-$norm, $B=(\sum |x_i|=1)$ is covered by $\Lambda$, a collection of open balls wrt $1-$norm, then for each point $x$ in $B$, exists a $2-$norm ball $O_x\ni x$ contained in an open $1-$norm ball in $\Lambda$. Finitely many $O_x$ cover $B$ by compactness in $2-$norm. Each of these $O_x$ is contained in some $U_x\in \Lambda$. These $U_x$s cover $B$.
